# Find minimum 3 duplicate value which is common in 4 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to find minimum 3 duplicate value with count which is common in 4 tables.

I have the tables visitorA, visitorB, visitorC, visitorD, all having a column named `username`:

```
visitorA      visitorB      visitorC      visitorD
username      username      username      username      
-------       -------       -------       -------       
kiran         imran         micro         sayeed
ayush         swapnil       kiran         maheer
sayeed        sanjay        jerin         sanjay
jerin         maheer        swapnil       micro
swapnil       rajat         sanjay        swapnil
```

Expected Output

```
swapnil 4
sanjay  3
```

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Why do you have 4 similar tables? Consider one table, for all visitors.

Comment: Do you require 3 _different_ tables, as the accepted answer? Or just same name 3 times?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of getting the desired result is by the use of `UNION ALL` and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT username, COUNT(DISTINCT src) AS cnt
FROM (
   SELECT username, 'A' AS src
   FROM visitorA

   UNION ALL

   SELECT username, 'B' AS src
   FROM visitorB

   UNION ALL

   SELECT username, 'C' AS src
   FROM visitorC

   UNION ALL

   SELECT username, 'D' AS src
   FROM visitorD) AS t
GROUP BY username
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT src) >= 3
```

**Note:** `DISTINCT` is required *only* in the case where there can be duplicate `username` values in either of the four `visitorX` tables. If `username` is unique you can leave the `DISTINCT` keyword out.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `UNION ALL` to takeout all user list including duplicate values from all the four tables then we can use `GROUP BY` username and `HAVING COUNT` to check the duplicate count to the expected times.

```
SELECT username, COUNT(username) total 
FROM(
    SELECT username FROM visitorA
    UNION ALL
    SELECT username FROM visitorB
    UNION ALL
    SELECT username FROM visitorC
    UNION ALL
    SELECT username FROM visitorD) t
GROUP BY username
HAVING COUNT(username) >= 3
```

Comment: what is the difference between your answer and Giorgos Betsos' answer

Comment: @PrateikDarji, it works. (count(username) instead of count(distinct username)).

Comment: I have noticed after I posted my answer that he has used `DISTINCT` in the count but I am not.

Comment: With a proper explanation instead of "try this", it could be worth an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to join and group the results on the username, then add another condition on each group to obtain the users that appears at least 3 times.

```
SELECT a.username, count(a.username) as total FROM a JOIN b ON    
a.username=b.username JOIN c on b.username = c.username JOIN d on 
c.username = d.username 
GROUP BY a.username HAVING count(a.username)>2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
WITH CTE AS
(SELECT * FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table2
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table3
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table4)

SELECT USERNAME, COUNT(*) FROM CTE GROUP BY USERNAME HAVING COUNT(*)>=3;
```